# Getting a grid count google apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid but I see no way to get an actual count from a grid class.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: can you clarify what you want / need ? is it the number of rows/columns that are used in a grid? where and when do you need to get it ?

Comment: Yes, essentially I would like to make my UI APP a bit more dynamic with a vertical panel widget covered with many horizontal panel widgets.  I would like to be able to add/remove horizontal widgets via the cunning use of a button with a serverhandler onclick(ok so it's not so cunning)  Therefore I would need to know the count and be able to iterate through the widgets.  Since the horizontal panels(nor the vertical) seem to not offer a way to do this in one object I assumed having a grid would do this unfortunately that does not occur either.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a no go eh?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value in a hidden text box and use createFlexTable() itself is a dynamic style grid.